# How can I modify this code to reference cells in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SortDataWithoutHeader()
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

my interface buttons are in a sheet called 'tools' and the data being manipulated is in a sheet called 'data'

Comment: Anywhere you have a `Range` call, add `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").` beforehand.

Comment: It gives me "Runtime error 1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined error. Screenshot https://imgur.com/kYKKfKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. A `With` statement can be helpful here. Note the periods before every `Range`, `Cells`, and `Rows` call within the `With` block. The period is necessary to actually reference `ws`, which is the sheet you want.

```
Sub SortDataWithoutHeader()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    With ws
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```